# Does Geowebcache uses JAI?

Tags: geoserver

Do I need to install JAI when I use Geowebcache? Or can I just use one or the other?
I've installed JAI and uses Geowebcache, I'm not sure if I take out the JAI step it would have given the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoWebCache does not use JAI.

If you are using the GeoServer WMS to generate the tiles for GeoWebCache, then installing a native version of JAI would improve the WMS rendering performance. Keep in mind that if your tile set does not change after the initial rendering, then there isn't much of an advantage if you are willing to wait a bit longer to render the tiles for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

According to GeoServer's user manual, you have already installed the pure Java version of JAI:

«The Java Advanced Imaging API (JAI) is an advanced image manipulation library built by Oracle. GeoServer requires JAI to work with coverages and leverages it for WMS output generation. By default, GeoServer ships with the pure Java version of JAI, but for best performance, install the native JAI version in your JDK/JRE.

In particular, installing the native JAI is important for all raster processing, which is used heavily in both WMS and WCS to rescale, cut and reproject rasters. Installing the native JAI is also important for all raster reading and writing, which affects both WMS and WCS. Finally, native JAI is very useful even if there is no raster data involved, as WMS output encoding requires writing PNG/GIF/JPEG images, which are themselves rasters.»

Taken from *GeoServer 2.3.x User Manual » Running in a Production Environment » [Java Considerations](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html)*

Comment: Thanks. I installed the Native JAI because they say it helps the performance. But I see now it won't make much difference